# What is this symbol in my Renault Arkana dashboard

Tags: renault, dashboard

I was driving with cruise control one day and saw this symbol. Never saw it again. What can this mean? I can't find anything about it in the manual.

It looks like an exclamation mark with something resembling some signal (three waves of wifi or something).

It's the one under 110 limit.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Unfortunately, the internet at work is not playing today and my system is not displaying images (argh). Hopefully someone else can see your image and let you know what it means. If not, I'll take a look when I get home this evening and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have two cruise control buttons on your steering wheel. One is for regular cruise control and the other one next to it with a car symbol on it is for adaptive cruise control.

Adaptive cruise control uses a radar sensor on the front of your car to ping the car in front of you to measure its distance, and then maintain a selectable distance from that car within a speed tolerance that you can set.

I think the icon on your instrument panel indicated that there was no vehicle within range of the radar sensor, so the system defaulted to regular cruise control.

You can test this conjecture by activating adaptive cruise control again when there is no vehicle in front of you.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything in the manual, but my guess would be that the car is indicating that it cannot connect to any registered phone. If you don't have a phone connected (or bluetooth is off), you might see this signal (I get similar in my Hyundai)